# How should support be provided for existing software?

Tags: team-management, time-management, maintenance

In our organization, sales people and administrators ask developers for support whenever they experience a problem. How should support time be structured/provided for existing software without constantly interrupting developers with direct requests to fix things?

Comment: I refactored the question quite heavily for clarity. Please feel free to edit your question further if you have additional information, or if my edits misrepresent your issue.

Comment: Please expand these 'existing softwares'. Are they softwares built in-house or third-part softwares?

Answer (score 3):

#### Responsibility for Change Control

Whether the request is for new features, bug-fixes, or support for developed software, what you're really talking about is *change control*. Change control is the process your organization uses (or fails to use) to manage scope and resource constraints on a project.

Regardless of the framework, here's how responsibility for change control should be handled at the conceptual level:

1. Projects should define a hand-off to a support team/organization for completed projects.
2. Projects should define a support process for projects-in-progress to prevent diverting project resources in unanticipated ways.
3. Change control requests should be triaged and prioritized by someone who can make *business decisions* about whether resources should be diverted from feature development to support for any given issue.

   *Note: In Scrum, this person should be the Product Owner. Other frameworks may task a steering committee, project sponsor, or other executive with this authority, which may then be further delegated to someone else (e.g. the project manager) if desired.*

Note that all responsibility ultimately rests with senior management. While the project manager is responsible for recommending controls such as a formal *change management process* to senior management, **the management team remains responsible for funding the process and keeping it aligned with business interests.**

#### Support Outside of a Project

If support requests are an ongoing business process rather than a byproduct of a specific project, then an organization needs to build a process around that need. While some process frameworks such as [Kanban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_%28development%29#The_Kanban_method) or Lean can be leveraged for repeating or ongoing processes, technical support itself is not typically considered a project, and is not usually managed by a project manager.

Because technical support is a business process rather than a defined project, applying project management methodologies (as opposed to process control methodologies) is usually not appropriate. However, one can't over-generalize here, so your mileage may vary.